# iOS Provisioning Portal Crashes When Submit Certificate Request

Tags: ios, safari, crash, certificate, provisioning

I have several apps in the iStore for iPhone/iPad. I was notified that my certificates expired. I followed the steps on https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/create.action. However, Safari crashes when I submit! Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems using other browsers than Safari, but it has always worked for me in Safari.

1. Have you tried more than once?
2. Did you try restarting your Mac?
3. Updating Safari/OS X?

If none of the above works I think you'll have to contact Apple for support.